# ASP.NET HTTP Handler Unrecognized Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, handler, httphandler

I have ASP.NET handler. But when I try to call it it says :

**The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable**.

```
namespace SimpleHTTPHanlder
{
    public class SimpleHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        #region IHttpHandler Members

        bool IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }
        void IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            HttpResponse response = context.Response;
            response.Write("<html><body><h1>Wow.. We created our first handler");
            response.Write("</h1></body></html>");
        }
        #endregion
    }
}




<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="vishal.nayan" type="SimpleHTTPHanlder.SimpleHandler"/>
      </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I try to make request like this, but with unsuccess:

```
http://localhost:60223/SimpleHTTPHanlder/vishal.nayan
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at our code which works, some ideas:

- Try adding the handler under `system.webServer` instead of `system.web`
- Try adding the attribute `preCondition="integratedMode"`
- Try specifying a `name` attribute

Answer (score 0):

I think as you have written your path as

```
  http://localhost:60223/SimpleHTTPHanlder/vishal.nayan.
```

Instead of this try

```
 http://localhost:60223/vishal.nayan
```

This is because your path element contain vishal.nayan only.

```
 <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="vishal.nayan" type="SimpleHTTPHanlder.SimpleHandler"/>
      </httpHandlers>
```

if you still have issue then tell me does you have hosted on IIS or IIS express ?

If you have configured in IIS ( IIS 7 or 7.5 later then you have to configure in

```
   <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="test" verb="*" path="vishal.nayan" type="SimpleHTTPHanlder.SimpleHandler"/>
    </handlers>
    ...... other configuration
   </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
http://localhost:60223/SimpleHTTPHanlder/vishal.nayan
```

is it a copy/paste with a typo ? ( Hanlder )